# Redmine installation on Ubuntu ... now what?

Tags: ubuntu, redmine

I've been tinkering/testing with Ubuntu Server 10.04 Beta LAMP stack in a VM and now I've come to the Redmine install.  I found a package for it, and issued:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
sudo apt-get install redmine
```

Which (I think almost) worked, but I've no idea how to test it, or even know if it's configured.

How do I test it? I'm using 10.04 server so I don't have a local GUI.

Comment: I should mention that this installation methodology is the current i'm hoping to get to work, having tried several how-to's, not the least of which is the install guide on the Redmine site itself.

Comment: I'm guessing you've never setup a web application like Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress, etc. right?

Comment: Not much of a guess, but yeah.  Beyond setting up Apache to control my access to subversion repositories and serve up static html, I'm really a user who administers when I need the tools to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the redmine Ubuntu package requires some manual configuration before you can get started. Now that redmine is installed, you still have to make it accessible through a real web server. An easy way to do this is with Apache with the mod_passenger plugin.

Just edit your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` (or `default-ssl`), adding:

```
RailsBaseURI /redmine
PassengerDefaultUser www-data
```

Then configure `/etc/redmine/default/database.yml` as necessary and run `ln -s /usr/share/redmine/public /var/www/redmine`. That should do the trick.

You can read more at http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you to http://IP.address.of.server?

At some point during the Redmine install you would've likely setup an Apache virtual host that would've had a `ServerAlias` directive with `somedomain.com`, assuming you have DNS setup for that domain to resolve to your VM's IP address.  If not, you can get away with editing your HOSTS file.

If so, you need to go to http://somedomain.com in your browser to see/use Redmine.

Comment: Half the battle here is describing my problem, the other is not having configured apache servers.  I can hit the apache server with "http://ww.xx.yy.zz" and see static content, but I don't know where I'd find the redmine ... does it come up on a non-standard port, or should it be 'right there'.  

My first desire is to see if the package installed correctly.

Comment: I usually install Web applications manually (because I like to see what's going on, make sure each step works ok, etc.).  However, you should be able see if the installer created a new Apache site in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Comment: @gravyface: Not an answer, but it does give me some threads I can read up on (virtual host configuration, which didn't happen).  Thanks for the lead.

Comment: How is that not an answer?  You gave very little, but yet I answered your question correctly and directly.

Comment: If want a _different_ answer, then you'll need to revise your question accordingly.

Comment: I guess you did answer it: the 'test' failed.  I need to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error:

```
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

So in order to apache2 configuration work ( `RailsBaseURI /redmine` and `PassengerDefaultUser www-data` ) I needed to install Passeger lib.

```
  $ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

Answer (score -1):

This tutorial (complete with screencast video) works like a charm for me;

https://www.simplified.guide/redmine/install-in-ubuntu